# Redirect on authentication based on user profile

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to get to grips with Razor pages (my previous experience is with web forms), and I'm running into difficulties with setting up a redirect after a user has logged in.

What I want to do is to look at some data about the user, and then redirect to a specific page based on the information.

In the default template provided by VS these lines of code handle the sign in:

```
var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Email, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: true);
if (result.Succeeded)
{
    _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
    return LocalRedirect(Url.GetLocalUrl(returnUrl));
}
```

I tried using a UserManager instance to get information about the logged in user, but it doesn't work (it just returns null).

```
var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Email, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: true);
if (result.Succeeded)
{
    _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
    var name = _userManager.GetUserName(HttpContext.User); //Returns null
    return LocalRedirect(Url.GetLocalUrl(returnUrl));
}
```

I'm guessing this is because the authentication cookie isn't set until the redirect page is loaded? (If I query the SignInManager immediately after result.Succeeded, it tells me the user isn't logged in).

Any pointers about the best technique for getting it to do what I want it to do would be much appreciated. Not entirely convinced the Razor pages documentation is up to scratch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in saying that cookie is not set until the page is reloaded.

However you are close - you already know the username - it is in `Input.Email`. Despite the confusing name of the variable, `_signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync` takes username, password and a bool ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt173779(v=vs.108).aspx#M:Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.SignInManager%602.PasswordSignInAsync(System.String,System.String,System.Boolean,System.Boolean))).

So to get the full user object you need to use `FindByNameAsync` [method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt151639(v=vs.108).aspx#M:Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager%602.FindByNameAsync(System.String)) on user manager:

```
var userObject = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(Input.Email);
```

and then do whatever you need to do to decide where to redirect.